# What is the difference between these 2 LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have 2 LINQ queries, one returns what I expect, the other doesn't and i'm trying to understand why. I'm trying to figure out if from all the nodes in Config, is there a node that is called "TEST" and its Selected attribute is True.

Query 1 - Which returns the right thing has the condition inside Any():

```
var res1 =
(from config in _config.CurrentSettings.Config let name = config.name select config).Any(
    config => config.name.Equals("TEST") && config.selected == true);
```

Query 2, which fails, has the condition inside Select:

```
(_config.CurrentSettings.Config.Select(config => config.name.Equals("TEST") && config.selected))
.Any();
```

Comment: `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<bool>` you need to use `Where` to filter the input sequence.

Comment: what is `let name = config.name` doing? its useless appreantly

Comment: Any returns a bollean, Select returns the data

Answer (score 5):

LINQ's `Any()` with no condition means "has at least one row". The first query specifies a condition, making it "has at least one row matching the condition".

To make the second query equivalent to first one, use `Any(flag => flag)`, or replace `Select` with `Where`. Both these options are inferior to the initial `Any`, with the condition inside, because they are not as readable.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing here is useless.

```
(from config in _config.CurrentSettings.Config let name = config.name select config)
```

You can narrow it down to this

```
_config.CurrentSettings.Config.Any(config => config.name.Equals("TEST") && config.selected == true);
```

Which will perform same as your first block of code.

The `Select` methods converts an ienumerable into another form using a selector 
you give.
 parameter-less `Any` returns true if sequence contains any element. otherwise returns false.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try:

```
var isTestSelected = _config.CurrentSettings.Config.Any(config => config.name.Equals("TEST") && config.selected);
```

Looking at the documentation for the [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) methods, may provide some insight.

If you look at the Parameters section of each of those links, you'll see that while both methods accept a `Func`, their usage is actually different.

**Any**

> *predicate*
>   Type: `System.Func<TSource, Boolean>` A function to test each
>   element for a condition.

**Select**

> *selector* 
>   Type: `System.Func<TSource, TResult>` A transform function to
>   apply to each element.

So, in your Query1 example, you're applying a transform (or map) to each item in your collection, which declares a local name variable 
`let name = config.name` (which is not being used), and then just returns the object as is (without actually transforming anything) `select config`.  This bit of code is superfluous, and can be removed.

Your `Any()` lambda is doing all the work in Query1, by filtering items that don't match your lambda predicate.

In Query2, you're passing a filtering lambda to a transform function, and then using a filtering function without a filter.

There are many different ways to get your desired result using Linq.  I encourage you to look at the different mapping (selector) and filtering (predicate) functions provided by the framework ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)).